# How to get dropdown product attribute value Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I have created a **product drop-down attribute** and assigned a value to it on the product.

I need them on product detail page.

```
$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_type')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $_attributeValue;
```

OR

```
$_attributeValue = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $_attributeValue;
```

Output as

> NO

On `print($_attributeValue)` my output

`Magento\Framework\Phrase Object ( [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => No [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array ( ) )`

But for **product text attribute** I get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be this

```php
$attribute_code = 'product_type';
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

or maybe

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('product_type');
```

Comment: The first code returns No and second one empty, This code also works for product text attribute.

Comment: $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_type')->getFrontendLabel() works and in product detail in more information i can see the value i have selected for code 'product_type' but dont know why this code is not working

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: ->setStoreId(0) will get data based on store few blogs has this, By issue is different.

Comment: I am not getting for color dropdown attribute in too

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the product from item which dint work for me

```
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

This one works

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$product_type = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```